# Finding all equivalent keys in an array in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide, indexof

I am using Selenium IDE, the data file I am using has multiple references to the same key.

I have arrays with the following type of information:

```
Array1: ['green','blue','green','red']
```

Created using this selenium code:

```
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>new Array('green','blue','green','red');</td>
<td>Array1</td>
</tr>
```

I am using this Selenium Code to get the index of the key 'green' (Result was 0 as expected):

```
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>javascript{storedVars['Array1'].indexOf("green")}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

However I need to also reference tomato, I have tried this to reference the second instance of the key `storedVars['Array1'].indexOf("green")]` (result was 'null', expected 2):

```
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>javascript{storedVars['Array1'].indexOf("green")[1]}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I also tried this (result was 0, expected 2):

```
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>javascript{storedVars['Array1'].indexOf("green",1)}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

It seems as though Selenium or javascript is ignoring the start variable for indexOf, I understand this was supported from Javascript 1.6 I am using the latest Firefox (version 50)

I would appreciate any pointers or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create two function within user extensions, to create the array and then retrieve the array (this had the benefit of moving the loop from Selenium (slow) into a javascript function (fast). This provides the full objective of getting the multiple references within the array.

```
 Selenium.prototype.doGetCommonDisabilityArray = function(key,record){
 var result = storedVars.obj2[key];
 if (result == null) {
 storedVars[record]=[];
 return;
 }
 storedVars[record]=result;
 }
```

The above caters for when there is no key found, and creates the array. Use in Selenium IDE as so:

```
<tr>
<td>addToDisabilityArray</td>
<td>${NAT090ClientIdentifier}</td>
<td>${NAT090DisabilityTypeIdentifier}</td>
</tr>
```

and

```
    Selenium.prototype.doAddToDisabilityArray = function(key,record) {

    var children;
    if (key in storedVars.obj2) {
        children = storedVars.obj2[key];
    } else {
        children = [];
    }
    children.push(record);
    storedVars.obj2[key] = children;
    }
```

Where:

**doAddToDisablityArray** is the function called within Selenium IDE

**key** is the value I am looking for in the array

**obj2** is the temporary array of key references

Use in Selenium IDE in this format:

```
<tr>
<td>getCommonDisabilityArray</td>
<td>${NAT120ClientIdentifier}</td>
<td>CommonDisabilityListArray</td>
</tr>
```

Note that it was important to ensure that the user-extension.js was referenced within Selenium IDE as 'Selenium Core Extensions' otherwise we didn't have access to the variables between functions.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't exactly what you're asking but it DOES work:

```
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['Array1'].lastIndexOf('green')}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

But, like you I can't get fromIndex to be respected. I went to here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ac6CT/ to detect my JS version which appears to only be 1.5 (FF 50.1.0)

Comment: My version was also confirmed as 1.5 0 my solution was eventually to create a function within my user extension file. I'll post it in case it helps others...